# "I'd rather see him with you than with anyone else"?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions, phrase-requests, syntactic-analysis

A female friend of mine just got together with a guy I know and I wanted to tell her that he's better off with her than with anyone else but I'm not sure if I'm phrasing this right:

"I'd rather see him with you than with anyone else"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although grammatical, the statement prompts the question *why?* There could be several reasons for it.

Comment: I get what you mean. Should have probably said that I'm very close to the guy and my friend was worried whether I would approve of the relationship or not. Do you reckon it makes sense in this context? Is there a more natural expression you would use?

Comment: You could just say that you're delighted to see them getting together, or go overboard and say you think they're ideally suited.

Comment: I'd be inclined to simply say "I'm glad to seem him with you".  Not using a "than" avoids bringing up doubts that there might have been another person specific person floating around out there that you disprove or that  maybe you are merely resigned to the fact that he has to be with someone rather than yourself (yes you said he was just a friend, but the 'rather, than' somehow conveys a flavor to me that you might prefer 'none of the above')  Just my 2cents.. others will feel differently.

Comment: This construction is actually ambiguous.  Another interpretation would be that you (the speaker) are going to see the guy and want someone to join you in the process.  You would prefer the person who accompanies you to be the person you are talking to rather than someone else.  Less ambiguous wording would more accurately describe the action you would prefer, like "I'd rather he be with you than with anyone else."  That associates the action with him instead of you ("he be" rather than "I see").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I'd rather see him with you than with anyone else" - your sentence is grammatically correct. The most common (positive) meaning likely to be attached to it would be that 'you are the best person for him.'

Comment: I'd prefer the "you are the best person for him" that you suggest as I think the way the OP presents it brings up some odd misgivings around the edges.